# FastAPI callback doesn't send the callback call

Tags: python, callback, fastapi

I'm following [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/openapi-callbacks/) to implement a quick callback example. For convenience, I make the callback target endpoint in the same app, but launch two services so to simulate the case where the callback target is in a different host.

In one shell, `uvicorn app:app --reload --port 8000`, and in another shell `uvicorn app:app --reload --port 12345`. Now in the third shell, call `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"John Doe"}' "http://127.0.0.1:8000/process?callback_url=http://127.0.0.1:12345"`

While the `/process` call works (I do see the "Processing input..." printed in the first shell, it seems the callback endpoint is never hit (all quiet in the second shell). Did I miss something here?

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl

app = FastAPI()


class Input(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Output(BaseModel):
    message: str


callback_router = APIRouter()


@callback_router.post("{$callback_url}/callback")
def process_notification(body: Output) -> None:
    pass


@app.post("/process", response_model=Output, callbacks=callback_router.routes)
def process(input: Input, callback_url: HttpUrl | None) -> Output:
    print("Processing input...")
    message = f"Hello, {input.name}!"
    return Output(message=message)


@app.post("/callback")
def callback(output: Output) -> str:
    print("Callback received...")
    message = f"it said {output.message}"
    return message
```

Comment: Okay, I read the docs again, and it seems the `callbacks` field in the `@app.post` decorator doesn't actually hit the callback endpoint, but just for documentation purpose?

Comment: Yes, it's just for the openapi specification to reflect what the callback will look like.

Comment: The callback parameter in decorators is for documentation purposes. To actually redirect to the endpoint you would return a RedirectResponse.